# Is it possible to filter the orders that are visible via WooCommerce REST API?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

We are running a WooCommerce shop and want to make our orders available to an external shipping contractor via the WooCommerce REST API.

However, not all orders are relevant to this contractor and he should not be able to access orders with only virtual products due to security and privacy reasons.

Is there a filter available where I can hide these orders from the REST API? I know how to do the filter, I just don't know if the right filter hooks exists to only filter posts (orders) accessed via the REST API. The WooCommerce Docs are not very clear on that subject. Thanks!

Comment: This may help you by any mean: https://www.thrinacia.com/blog/post/rest-api-sorting-paging-and-filtering

Could you please add more details in the question

Comment: You have PHP. Use it.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify it. I know how to do the filter, I just need the right filter hook.